# why am I getting: HTTP Error 500.30 error when publishing the Blazor server-side site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I've made my web app on Blazor server-side and I'm trying to publish it on a windows server.
I tried different methods to publish but all came to the same conclusion.

**HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure**
Here comes a link to the image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ndgb9Bh5BJH-tp_vR5vpfhWcr8BFgyh2/view?usp=sharing

**As you can see there is no index file! why that's missing?**

I used this instruction:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/

Why am I having this problem?
You can see the result on mangoscarf.com

Comment: Are you using Azure?

Comment: No, I don't. I want to upload my file to another server.

Comment: The cause of a 500.30 error can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log. So, try to check these logs. Besides, the common failure condition: The app is misconfigured due to targeting a version of the ASP.NET Core shared framework that isn't present. Check which versions of the ASP.NET Core shared framework are installed on the target machine. Please refer [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426395/).

Comment: I asked the host, both .net core and bitness are the same but still have this problem.Why there is no index file and there is an application file? is this correct?

Comment: "Why there is no index file and there is an application file?" Could you explain more detail about that, or you can capture a screenshot to explain more detail? Do you mean the application lost the Index page?

Comment: I added a link to my published file image. As you can see the index file is missing. Also should mention used this instruction:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/

Answer (score 1):

"ANCM In-Process Start Failure" is a generic error.

To get more information about the error go to:

Azure Portal > your App Service > under development tools > open Console.

You can run the application through this console and you should see the actual error.

(Type the executable filename of your project, i.e. "omgwtf.exe" and press enter.)

Also check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5

Comment: But I don't use Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method:
Select the folder from the left menu and provide a folder path. You can provide any folder path where you want to publish your app.

Click on publish. Visual Studio will start publishing your application. If there are no build errors, then your application will be published successfully in the folder you have mentioned.

After the publishing is successful, you should move on to configure IIS.
more info on:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/