# Asp .Net Core 3.1 suddenly receive error 500.30

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hosting, iis-express, http-error

I have a solution with multiple project directory. One of them is for front-end. The one I use for front-end was working fine until today. Somehow it always met with Error 500.30. The only changes I made recently was only on others projects in which is all about creating Models, Services method and API Controller. I don't think it's possible for those kind of files to corrupt my Front-end project directory but after a long time research, I don't know what to look at. I have try turning my project Hosting Model to 'Out Of Process', view application log which return no error, yet still can't identify what cause the problem. Does anyone has any ideal?

Comment: Try reinstalling the hosting module

Comment: The server must of been upgraded and disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 which was a microsoft security update that was released last June.  Try adding following to beginning of the client code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  The new line will force client to use TLS 1.2.

Comment: Run a report and see what it says first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: The cause of a 500.30 error can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log. So, try to check these logs. Besides, the common failure condition: The app is misconfigured due to targeting a version of the ASP.NET Core shared framework that isn't present. Check which versions of the ASP.NET Core shared framework are installed on the target machine. Please refer [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426395/).